# Swedish conjugation, spoken vs written

Tags: syntax

In the Swedish language, I am presently trying to discern the proper translation of "*No, they're not*" as it is spoken and written in English. I determine:

> *Nej, det är de inte*

and

> *Nej, det är dem inte*

Which is correct?

I am interested in the differences between written and spoken Swedish while trying to conjugate for the pronoun '*they*', being '*de*' and '*dem*'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this and i am a native speaker of Swedish and i had to answer. I have no specific grammar training more than any other Swede and i speak what is referred to as "common" Swedish with no specific dialect (i am from the Stockholm region).

When speaking casually with friends i would respond

"*Nej det är dom inte*"

and when we say it fast it actually is more pronounced "*Nä deärom inte*". "*Deärom*" is not a correct word, but to speak faster we drop som letters and that is more of how we pronounce it.

Swedish people in general have a hard time differentiating between "de" and "dem" thats why we commonly just use "dom" to safeguard us against both in spoken language. A lot of people write "spoken languge" thats when "dom" sneaks in, in written language, but this is considered bad practice.

I was taught the following in school when i was young:

If you don't know when to use "*de*" or "*dem*" try replacing it with "*jag*" or "*mig*".

Is "save a piece of cake for them" called:

"*Spara en tårtbit åt de?*" 
or 
"*Spara en tårtbit åt dem?*"

If i want to save a pice of cake for myself i say "*Spara en tårtbit åt mig*" and "mig" is the same form as "dem". So it is "*Spara en tårtbit åt dem?*" that is the correct version.

Placing this context in your example it will become:

"*Nej det är jag inte*" and "*jag*" is the same as "*de*" so correct Swedish grammar would be

"*Nej det är de inte*"

But this was what i was taught in school as a 10 year old kid.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my knowledge Thomas.